# android 3d live wallpaper - what engine to use?

Tags: android, 3d, live-wallpaper

I saw this live 3d wallpaper and was wondering how it is made, e.g. what engine should be used to make it? From what I found, Unity3D currently does not support making wallpaper...

[image]

Comment: This question looks similar to this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165727/live-wallpaper-with-game-engine-or-not

Comment: @Roger Travis, hi, do you know how to make 3d gyro-effect like in video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XyIRhkwYvE ?

Answer (score 7):

If you would like a true 3d live wallpaper, you can check out Rajawali here:

https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliWallpaperTemplate

Follow his tutorials and utilize that template and you can make some really amazing live wallpapers. I use it myself and found it very fun and educational.

Check out this live wallpaper made with the Rajawali library:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PM.AutumnGrove3DFREE

It's not mine but it definitely shows the potential with the Rajawali library.

Hopes this helps you and anyone else looking to make a 3d live wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can make 3D wallpapares, but try with

[AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
or
[Cocos2D](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

Comment: Yes your right, both andengine and cocos2d are primarily 2d engines,but can do pseudo 3d (where 3d assets are rendered at set angles to 2d sprites). I created the following 2d wallpaper called 'skydiving ninjas' using andengine using its built in box2d physics engine, wrote it in about two days including drawing the basic graphics. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.deanezra.android.skydivingninjas&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dskydiving+ninjas+deanezra&pcampaignid=APPU_1_en5nVvCYFYHMaJ7iq8gF

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) and the [Unity2Eclipse](http://blog.appjigger.com/category/unity3d/unity2eclipse/) plugin, it's the easiest way I've found. Be warned, it's still beta and you have to use Unity 3.4 to get it to work. I see a lot of Unity crashes in my error reports and my retention rate is pitiful

I've got some examples of what you can do if your into Sharks, Neon, Zombies and Birds they are worth checking out http://www.app8ite.com/live-wallpapers/

Comment: Has this stability problem changed at all since you wrote this? I already use Unity, so this plugin would be ideal if it wasn't crashing so often.

Comment: @App8ite Unity2Eclipse is not free. Do you know how to transform from an Android generated app (by Unity) to Android live wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Uni2LwP](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/7647) (not free) and Unity3D. This new plugin works very well with almost every version of Unity.
Check dev thread for more information : [Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/172275-Uni2LwP-Create-Live-Wallpapers-with-Unity-3-4-2-3-5-7-4-0!)

Answer (score 0):

From analyzing the screenshot you've provided, it seems like a pretty simple scene, with some post-effects added on top of the final image. Unity engine makes it easy to do stuff like that, with its visual editor, good asset import pipeline and post-processing chains. There are others engines that you could use to achieve similar visual quality (Rajawali is a particular good example), but it'd be a much more tedious task.

The negative side of using Unity is that it is somewhat heavy - it's expected to have an APK of around 9 MB in size for an empty scene. This doesn't really matters if you have a resource-heavy live wallpaper, though.

I've recently released uLiveWallpaper - a Unity asset that makes it possible to create live wallpapers for Android using Unity 5. It is well-tested and reliable, creates projects for Android Studio, complete with placeholder code to get you started.

Check it out!

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ulivewallpaper-develop-android-live-wallpapers-with-unity-5.375255/

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Um, what issue OP is trying to fix?.. He asked which engine he could use to get a similar level of quality. Obviously, this kind of visuals is achievable with Unity, and it is now possible to create live wallpapers with it.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.